# String contains any items in an array (case insensitive)

Tags: php, string, arrays, contains

How can i check if a `$string` contains any of the items expressed in an array?

```
$string = 'My nAmE is Tom.';
$array = array("name","tom");
if(contains($string,$array))
{
// do something to say it contains
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no indication of if partial word matching is desired.  Do you need word boundaries?

Comment: Hi @mickmackusa, what about partial string matching?

Comment: My question to the asker is asking if `My username is Tom.` should result in a match for `name`.  This is a common fork in business requirements for developers.  Sometimes, making a partial match is absolutely fine; other times, it is critical that only full-words are matched.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

is that what you wanted? i hope that code is compiling :)

```
$string = 'My nAmE is Tom.';
$array = array("name","tom");
if(0 < count(array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', explode(' ', $string)), $array)))
{
  //do sth
}
```

Comment: This would fail on the strings: "Tom, what do you think?" "His 'name' is Tom." among many others.

Comment: Why call `strlower()` n times after exploding?  It makes better sense to call `strtolower()` before exploding.  The `0 <` is unnecessary -- the return from `count()` will be a truthy value when greater than zero.  This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Comment: This assumes the array only contains single words and not phrases.

Answer (score 112):

I don't think there is a built-in function that will handle what you want.  You could easily write a `contains()` function however:

```
function contains($str, array $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $a) {
        if (stripos($str,$a) !== false) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why not regexp? I think its not to diffucult to interpret preg_match('/'.implode('|', $arr).'/i', $str)

Comment: @velop While a valid approach, that is not functionally equivalent. The array would need to be written in consideration of being matched via regex. Otherwise if any strings in the array include a / or | or any other modifiers it will provide unexpected results.

Comment: Tip for developers using Laravel: this method exists in the framework from 5.7 onwards as `Str::contains(string $haystack, array|string $needles)` and as  `str_contains(string $haystack, array|string $needles)` for version 5.6. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-contains

Comment: @alexkb Would be cool with a Str:: helper function that would either return the index: number or index(s): number[] from the Str::contains instead of a boolean

Answer (score 18):

Using the accepted answer:

```
$string = 'My nAmE is Tom.';
$array = array("name","tom");
if(0 < count(array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', explode(' ', $string)), $array)))
{
  //do sth
}
```

Just a side note that the if statement could be changed to:

```
if(0 < count(array_intersect(explode(' ', strtolower($string)), $array)))
```

since it's not really necessary to use array_map to apply `strtolower` to each element. instead apply it to the initial string.

Comment: This (along with the accepted answer) matches whole words rather than substrings so if you need to match more than whole words you should probably use @zombat 's answer.

Comment: Note that this answer will not match `tom` to `tom.` because the explosion on spaces does not trim the punctuation character.  You might enjoy `str_word_count()` here with a format parameter of `1`.

Answer (score 10):

One more workaround for contains function

```
function contains($string, $array, $caseSensitive = true)
{
    $strippedString = $caseSensitive ? str_replace($array, '', $string) : str_ireplace($array, '', $string);
    return $strippedString !== $string;
}
```

PS. as for me, I'm just using it without function...

```
if (str_replace($array, '', $string) !== $string) {
    // do it
}
```

Comment: The cleaner/leaner version of this answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66985649/2943403) because it doesn't bother making two unnecessary `strlen()` calls.

Answer (score 8):

We can check if any element of array is exists in a given string.

```
$string = 'My nAmE is Tom.';
$array = array("name","tom");

if(str_replace($array, '', strtolower($string)) !== strtolower($string)) {
   // If String contains an element from array      
   // Do Something
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. I would prefer [mb_strtolower](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mb-strtolower.php) for utf8 characters.

Comment: By calling `strtolower()` (or `mb_strtolower()`) and assigning to `$lower` before the `if` condition, you can simplify the condition to `if (str_replace($needles, '', $lower) !== $lower) {`.

Comment: From an academic point of view, this answer cannot enjoy an early return if it findd a match with the first needle in the array ...it would keep re-scanning and replacing strings until the entire array of needles was iterated.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this would work:

```
$string = 'My nAmE is Tom.';
$array = array("name", "tom");
foreach ($array as $token) {
    if (stristr($string, $token) !== FALSE) {
        print "String contains: $token\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Will this do the job?

```
$words = explode(" ", $string);
$wordsInArray = array();
foreach($words as $word) {
    if(in_array($word, $array)) {
        $wordsInArray[] = $word;
    }
}
```

Comment: This only matches whole words.

Comment: Hi @apokryfos, How to match partial-string also?

Comment: For the asker's sample data, this answer will not match `tom` to `tom.` because the explosion on spaces does not trim the punctuation character.  You might enjoy `str_word_count()` here with a format parameter of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$input = preg_quote('blu', '~'); // don't forget to quote input string!
$data = array('orange', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'pink', 'brown', 'black');

$result = preg_grep('~' . $input . '~', $data);
print_r($result);

?>
```

Comment: This unexplained answer appears to have completely ignored the details and sample data in the posted question.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ideal task to familiarize yourself with regular expressions so that you have a robust, easily adaptable, and direct script.

It is important to understand your own criteria for matching.

1. Do you want case-insensitive matching?
2. Do you want whole word or partial matching?
3. Do you need to support the possibility of encountering multibyte/unicode characters?

Here is a battery of patterns that demonstrate a few likely combinations.  Notice that most of the tooling is done via "pattern modifiers" after the closing pattern delimiter.  The `\b` means a "word boundary"; if you are not familiar with this metacharacter, please invest in more research and find other posts on Stack Overflow that implement them.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Jh0Zb))

```
$string = 'My nAmE ïs Tom.';

// case-sensitive matching, including partial matching
$array = ['foo', 'nAmE'];
$regex[] = '#' . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $array)) . '#';

// case-insensitive matching, including partial matching
$array = ['foo', 'om'];
$regex[] = '#' . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $array)) . '#i';

// case-insensitive matching, full word matching only
$array = ['foo', 'tom'];
$regex[] = '#\b(?:' . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $array)) . ')\b#i';

// case-insensitive matching, full word matching only, multibyte aware
$array = ['foo', 'ïs'];
$regex[] = '#\b(?:' . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $array)) . ')\b#iu';


foreach ($regex as $r) {
    if (preg_match($r, $string, $m)) {
        echo "found '$m[0]' using $r on $string\n";
    } else {
        echo "no match using $r on $string\n";
    }
}
```

By using a delimiter which is included in `preg_quote()`'s list of escaped characters (e.g. `#`), you can simply call `preg_quote` by its name inside of `array_map()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reusable helper function that uses the PHP 8+ function [`str_contains`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php):

```
function str_contains_any($haystack, $needles, $case_sensitive)
{
    foreach ($needles as $needle)
    {
        if (str_contains($haystack, $needle) || (($case_sensitive === false) && str_contains(strtolower($haystack), strtolower($needle))))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Usage example:

```
$haystack = 'This is a load of shizzle';
$needles = ['fudge', 'shizzle'];
$match_found = str_contains_any($haystack, $needles, true); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function contains($str, $arr)
{
  $ptn = '';
  foreach ($arr as $s) {
    if ($ptn != '') $ptn .= '|';
    $ptn .= preg_quote($s, '/');
  }
  return preg_match("/$ptn/i", $str);
}

echo contains('My nAmE is Tom', array('name', 'tom'));
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  For clarity, this will echo an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do with array_intersect() function, Try below code :

```
function checkString(array $arr, $str) {

  $str = preg_replace( array('/[^ \w]+/', '/\s+/'), ' ', strtolower($str) ); // Remove Special Characters and extra spaces -or- convert to LowerCase

  $matchedString = array_intersect( explode(' ', $str), $arr);

  if ( count($matchedString) > 0 ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `return array_intersect(str_word_count(strtolower($str), 1), $arr);`?

Answer (score 0):

I have done some testing because I needed to check user inputs against a list of words we didn't allow.

I have found that converting everything to lowercase (because my list is lowercase) and then using array intersect was by far the fastest.

```
    **First Option I Tested**
    $tempString= explode(' ',strtolower($string));
    $foundWords = array_intersect($tempString,$profanities);
    Time taken: 0.00065207481384277 

    **The second option I tested**
    $tempWords = explode(' ',$words);
    foreach ($tempWords as $word)
    {
        foreach ($profanities as $profanity)
        {
            if (stripos($word,$profanity) !== false) return true;
        }
    }
    Time Taken: 0.024131059646606
```

Comment: Exploding on spaces then comparing whole elements is not reliable then there may be ANY kind of punctuation in the input string.

Answer (score 0):

there is easier Method

```
   $string = 'My nAmE is Tom.';
   $convert=explode(" ",$string,5);
   if(in_array("My", $convert)){

      echo "Ja";
   }else{

      echo "Nein";
   }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is ignoring the asker's requirement to search the string with multiple needles.

Answer (score 0):

```php
/**
 * ! Only assumes that $needles strings does not contain the character '|'
 */
function contains(string $haystack, array $needles)
{
    $regex = '/' . str_replace('\|', '|', preg_quote(implode('|', $needles))) . '/i';

    return preg_match($regex, $haystack);
}
```

Code demo: https://3v4l.org/lY6qo#v8.1.4

Regex demo: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/E4s

Comment: This is not a solid approach.  If one of the needles needs to match a literal pipe, then your script will make that literal pipe into an OR metacharacter in the regex.  Another reason that I do not endorse this answer is because [`/` is not escaped by default via `preg_quote()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php).  If a needle contains a forward slash, then the pattern will break.  You need to explicitly nominate `/` as the delimiter parameter.