# Solving 'Argument #2 should be an array in'

Tags: php

I'm working with the following code [kindly supplied in an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461152/exempting-pdf-doc-and-xls-from-screen-grab-utility) but it generates the following errors

```
Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array in [path/to] on [Line #]
```

and

```
'Warning: Wrong parameter count for array_intersect() in [path/to] on [line #]'
```

Googleing the errors has produced no useful ideas - any help appreciated.

```
<?php
$types = array('.pdf', '.doc', '.xls');
if(0 < count(array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', $filename, $types)))) {
   echo 'One';
} else {
   echo 'Two';
}
?>
```

//update

```
<?php
$filename = array(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'mjwlink-url'));
$types = array('.pdf', '.doc', '.xls');
if(0 < count(array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', $filename), $types))) {
   echo 'One';
} else {
   echo 'Two';
}
```

?>

Comment: (After OP's update) Do you still get the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) takes exactly one argument, while [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with three arguments `($fun, $arr1, $arr2)` takes function `fun`, which must take two arguments itself: `fun(arg1, arg2)`. Look at Example #3 in [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)s docs page.

PS `$filename` variable is not initialized in your code?

---

**EDIT:** You probably want `array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', $filename), $types)` instead **(you put bracket in wrong place)...**

Comment: I've fixed the problems as you suggested and the code now executes, but doesn't perform it's purpose - all urls, even those ending in doc, pdf etc output condition two. Any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you print `$filename`'s contents?

Comment: Interesting, it literally prints the word 'Array'!

Comment: Even after printing contents with [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)? Does `get_post_meta`  return correct value then?

Comment: 'var_dump' prints  array(1) {   [0]=&gt;   array(1) {     [0]=&gt;     string(36) "http://www.prisonreformtrust.org.uk/"   } }

Answer (score 0):

For `array_map` the second argument needs to be an array, so I guess you should be passing `$types` there and not `$filename`.

Also, you need to pass at least two arrays into `array_intersect`. You're actually only passing one there.