# Remove all bad words (swearwords) from user input string?

Tags: php, string

I was trying to take out swear words from a string and thought I had it done, until someone on this site showed me this: http://codepad.org/LMuhFH4g

So, is there any way I can go over a string until its clean of all swear words.

```
$a = array( 'duck', 'chit', 'dsshole' ); 

$str = 'duchitck-you-dssduckhole'; 

$newString = str_ireplace($a,'',$str); 
$newString = str_ireplace('-','',$newString); 
$newString = trim($newString); 
echo $newString;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easy solution is to pass the fourth optional $count parameter.

```
do { 
    $str = str_ireplace(..., ..., ..., $count);
} while ($count);
```

To truly remove curse words though.... Good luck with that. There's just too many variations to ever completely filter natural language (word, werd, w0rd, w3rd, etc -- if someone wants to call someone a name badly enough, they'll find a way; websites tend to use moderation for a reason).

---

This approach is unusably basic by the way since it has no concept of actual words but just strings of characters (`assassinate` -> `inate`).  You can use regular expressions (the convenient `\b` word boundary), but at the end of the day, **[it's all pointless anyway](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html)**.

Comment: This'll do for now. 10 people in the world'll visit their site and they want things to be like some high tech... whatever.

Answer (score 1):

A function for censoring swear words from a txt file

PHP:

```
function censor($string)
{
    if ($string)
    {
        $badwords = file_get_contents("badwords.txt");
        $badwords = explode(",", $badwords);
        $replacewith = array();
        $index = 0;
        foreach ($badwords as $value) {
            $lengthOfStars = strlen($badwords[$index]) - 2;
            $replacewith[$index] = substr($badwords[$index], 0, 1).str_repeat("*", $lengthOfStars).substr($badwords[$index], -1);
            $index++;
        }
        $newstring = str_ireplace($badwords, $replacewith, $string);
        return $newstring;
    }
}

echo censor("Some swear words to censor");
```

badwords.txt:

swear,words

Outcome:

```
Some s***r w***s to censor
```

Comment: Probably should make sure whatever file you store the swear words in is a file that won't be snooped by 3rd parties. EDIT: Didn't mean to submit yet. Adding on > Some DNS providers may flag your website as being  18+/NSFW if it picks up on some of those keywords. At least that appears to have happened to me a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "contains" function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124527/string-contains-any-items-in-an-array-case-insensitive#2124557), you could do

```
$strFromSearchBox = 'duchitck you dssduckhole';
$theseWords = array('duck', 'chit', 'dsshole');

$newString = $strFromSearchBox;
while(contains($newString, $theseWords)) {
    $newString = str_replace($theseWords,'',$newString);
}

echo $newString;
```

Comment: no need to loop. `str_replace` will replace all occurrences of the words.

Comment: It might help to recheck. Someone might bypass it by expecting the collapse of a word. ffncknck becomes  fnck

Comment: @JosephKreifelsII that's what the while() loop is for.

Comment: @Matt I know that, I was replying to the guy who said you didn't need it.

Comment: @JosephKreifelsII my mistake, I misread your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
// array of all the banned strings
$swears = array(
        "a*s",
        "t*****s"
        // add all your swear words to this array
    );

$dirtyStr = "a*s and t*****s";

// remove all the banned strings
$cleanStr = str_replace($swears, '', $dirtyStr);

echo $dirtyStr;
> a*s and t*****s

echo $cleanStr;
> and
```

Comment: Try censoring your words if possible. There is no real need for the dirty words for understanding the problem/solution. I would also advise adding some textual explanation in addition to your code. It usually makes a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function censor($string)
{
if ($string)
{
    //badwordsarray
    $badwords = array('some', 'swear', 'word');
    //replacearray                      
    $replace =  array('s**e', 's***r', 'w**d'); 

    $newstring = str_ireplace($badwords, $replace, $string);
    return $newstring;
}
}
 $message = $_POST['message'];
 $filteredmessage = censor($message);
 echo $filteredmessage;
```