# How to trash a post if it contains specific explicit words?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to write a wordpress filter that would change the post status to trash if it contains explicit words, but I can't manage to get it to work. Could you please help me?

This is what I got so far:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'delete_invalid_posts', '99');
function delete_invalid_posts($data) {
    $false_titles = array("*****", "******");
  if (in_array($data['post_title'], $false_titles) {
    // If post data is invalid then
    $data['post_status'] = 'trash';
  }
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: Dupe: [String contains any items in an array (case insensitive)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2124527/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search the title for Explicit Words, you may use this code:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'delete_invalid_posts', 99);
function delete_invalid_posts($data) {
    $false_titles = array("*****", "******");
    $title_arr = explode(' ', $data['post_title']);
    $found = array_intersect($false_titles, $title_arr);
  if (!empty($found)) {
    $data['post_status'] = 'trash';
  }
  return $data;
}
```

I've not tested the code, So try it and if you have any question don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thank you, Shahin! I tried the solution you suggested, but still doesn't work. The post still gets published if it contains any of the words in the $false_titles. Might it be needed to use an hook instead of a filter?

Comment: @DavidFilat I've tested the code and it's working on my side, have you placed the code in your theme's functions.php?

Answer (score -1):

I might be wrong, but I think you are missing a closing parentheses here...?

Are you getting an error message?

`if (in_array($data['post_title'], $false_titles) // <--- HERE should be a ")"`

Like I said, I could be mistaken or there may be other issues...