# How to select several array elements and check if they are equal to variable

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to learn PHP on my own just by watching videos and reading blogs. I won't become a pro, I'm just a hobbyist. So I'm trying to code something but I got to a dead end.
So I have a string, let's say the string has some numbers f.e. 100, 2000, 3000. Using the explode method I convert the string to an array. Now I have a variable f.e.
`$var= 50;`

I want to see if $var is equal to the first or the third element of the array;

```php
<?php
    $str = " 100, 2000, 3000";
    $fevArr = explode(",", $str);
    $var = 50;
    if ($var == $fevArr['0'] or $var == $fevArr['2'] ) {
        echo "It is";
    } else {
        echo "It is not";
    }
?>
```

However I might have a lot of numbers in the string and I may want to check if $var is eaqual to many of them (say to the 1th, 10th, 20th, 101th, 300th ect). So I wonder if there is a way to make soemthing like this:

`if ($var == $fevArr['0', '9', '19',]) { ....`

In other words if there is a way to select several array elements at once.

Comment: No, such a syntax does not exist. But you could put the indexes you want to check into another array, and then _loop over_ that, to access each of them in the first array individually. But really you might probably rather want to use something like https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: $fevArray elements may contains whitespaces

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `array_keys` function. It will return all the indices that match the value you want to look for. Then you can use `array_intersect` function to check whether those indices match your indices you want to look for.

```
$var = 50;
$indices = [0, 2];
$keys = array_keys($fevArr, $var);
$matches = array_intersect($indices, $keys);

if(count($matches) > 0) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in_array($var, $fevArray)` ([see documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.in-array.php)) in your `if` statement.

Comment: Not sure you understood the question right. OP wants to check only specific positions in the array, not the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `array_search` ([link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)) which returns the key of the first match and `false` if no match found OR you can use `in_array` ([link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search)) method which will just check the existance.

Answer (score 0):

`in_array()` is not consistent just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445798/check-if-string-contains-a-value-in-array)

you can use the following code, I got it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124527/string-contains-any-items-in-an-array-case-insensitive)

```
function contains($str, array $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $a) {
        if (stripos($str,$a) !== false) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and you can apply it as:

```
if (contains($var, $fevArr) {
 echo "It is";
}
else {
 echo "It is not";
}
```

Comment: Not sure you understood the question right. OP wants to check only specific positions in the array, not the whole array.

Comment: It was not what I wanted, but it helped me figure a way around. So thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
    function contains_at_keys($haystack, $needle, $keys){
        //get all keys matching needle
        $matching_keys = array_keys($haystack, $needle);
        
        //return if these keys contain one or more of the keys to search
        return(sizeof(array_intersect($matching_keys, $keys)) > 0);
    }
    
    
    $str = "100, 2000, 3000, 50, 300, 50, 200";
    $fevArr = explode(",", $str);
    $var = 50;
    
    $keys = [3, 5];
    
    
    if(contains_at_keys($fevArr, $var, $keys)){
        echo("It is");
    } else {
        echo("It is not");
    }
?>
```